# Page keeps loading don't show result while loop php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a function that finds results from the database. I'm using `while loop` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to fetch results from the database. but the page keeps loading and doesn't show any errors.

**Loop**

```
  <?php while ($job = mysqli_fetch_assoc(find_all_jobs())) { ?>
  <tr class="custom-table-body-titles">
    <td><?php echo $job['updated-at']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="text-dark"><?php echo $job['title']; ?></a>
    </td>                
    <td>0/<?php echo $job['required_freelancers']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $job['delivery_time']; ?> Days</td>
    <td>$<?php echo $job['budget']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="job_details.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Apply</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

**Function**

```
function find_all_jobs() {
  global $connection;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY job_id DESC LIMIT 10";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed." . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
  }
  return mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign result of `find_all_jobs()` to a variable and run your loop:

```
<?php 
$jobs = find_all_jobs();
while ($job = mysqli_fetch_assoc($jobs)) { ?>
```

Because currently your `find_all_jobs()` executes on each `while` iteration. And therefore causes an **infinite loop**.